# Asp radio button list each three radio buttons in one row bootstrab

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, css

How can i get each 3 radio buttons from asp:RadioButtonList `rblbase` in one row like below code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio1
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio2
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio3
</div>
```

and row below it should be

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio3
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio4
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
    Radio5
</div>
```

**RadioButtonList**

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblbase" runat="server"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: set `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`

Answer (score 0):

Use **RepeatDirection = Horizontal** and set **margin-left,right** in your **CSS**. For example,

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblbase" runat="server" 
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="myRadioBtn"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then in your css code,

```
.myRadioBtn input[type="radio"]
{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Orelse you can use CellPadding and CellSpacing, like bellow,

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblbase" runat="server" 
RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2">
</asp:RadioButtonList> //change the values
```

Hope it helps :)